# django redirect

Tags: python, redirect, django

```
def auth_form(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = AuthForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            l = form.cleaned_data['login']
            p = form.cleaned_data['password']
            res = Users.objects.filter(login=l, password=p, is_deleted="0", is_blocked="0")
            if res:
                return render(request, 'auth/login.html', {'res':"Авторизация успешна!"})
            else:
                return render(request, 'auth/login.html', {'forms':form,'error':'Логин/пароль введен неверно!'})
    else:
        form = AuthForm()
    return render(request, 'auth/login.html', {'forms':form})
```

Как после успешной авторизации сделать redirect на www.yandex.ru

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    ...
    if res:
        return redirect('http://yandex.ru/')
    else:
```

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Answer (score 2):

[Простой редирект. С примерами.](https://sites.google.com/site/whitedjango/home/urlspyprostojredirektdjangoviewsgenericsimpleredirectto)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
....
def some(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://yandex.ru/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вручную брать объект модели, если в джанго есть встроенный механизм, записывающий объект в сессию? К тому же все пароли джанго хранит захэшированные, а вы передаёте "простые" - вы никогда не сделаете верную выборку из базы.
Если уж так "в лоб" - то посмотрите функцию redirect() в документации(кажется так называется), а вообще я бы посоветовал познакомиться [вот с этим](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

Comment: Я не могу использовать contrib.auth. Существует база клиентов необходимо внедрить технология cisco ISG авторизацию через portal, это делается для WIFI. Может в чем-то я и не прав.

Answer (score 0):

btw ответ нашел сам спасибо участникам данного треда

Ответ таков, что нужно использовать пользователя который уже есть у вас в админ панели в таблице пользователи