# Как вернуться на другую страницу Django

Tags: django

Я совсем новичок, поэтому даже не могу правильно озвучить проблему(
Сейчас делаю аутентификацию.
Есть такой шаблон:

```
{% block content %}
<p>Logged out!</p>  

<a href="{% url 'login'%}">Нажмите,чтобы войти в аккаунт</a>

<a href="{% url ''%}">Главная страница</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Мне необходимо вернуться на домашнюю страницу.При попытке ввода homepage/пустой строки выдает NoReverseMatch at /accounts/logout/.
Подскажите что не так, я понимаю, что плохо сформулировал проблему,не кричите.

Comment: Покажи код в `urls.py`.

Comment: Мне необходимо с шаблона логина сделать ссылку на начальную страницу.Сейчас, находясь в /accounts/logout/ если я ввожу {% url 'homepage'%}, то меня направит на 192....../accounts/logout/registration.Мне же необходимо зайти сюда 192....../registration

Answer (score 0):

[Связанное (ответ отсюда )](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58045/django-redirect)
views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def some(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://yandex.ru/')
```